# Coding homework dataset

Tags: data-request, programming

I would like to compare 25+ different coding (same programming language, if possible Java but other languages are fine too) implementations of the same homework. Where can I find such homework solution datasets?

Comment: Thanks, but the difficulty of obtaining such data set says long on the lack of data sharing culture in academia (+ privacy hampering research)... I am hoping some MOOC will release interesting data sets at some point, although they are fighting with lawyers right now (not sure how actively though).

Comment: Does it have to be homework specifically?  You could put together a '[code challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)' and post it [CodeGolf.SE](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Any homework is good, but simple homework is better (say < 200 SLOC). I fear golfing around might produce some weird code :) and also I'm interested in commonalities between solutions while SE golf solutions try to not overlap too much. I have just made my that that request PL-independent to broaden the search.

Comment: Are you looking for datasets?

Answer (score 5):

Including to other answers, here is one that may help to create a database.

> [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) is a series of challenging mathematical/computer
>   programming problems that will require more than just mathematical
>   insights to solve. Although mathematics will help you arrive at
>   elegant and efficient methods, the use of a computer and programming
>   skills will be required to solve most problems.

As the about section said, project Euler is a collection of many mathematical problems and users try to solve them one by one with programming languages. Unfortunately, there isn't a limitation on the programming language you have to use. But if someone track them and collect only those that want, it would create a nice database.

Comment: I don't know if Project Euler shares their participants' code, but many are hosting on GitHub: https://github.com/search?q=project+euler&ref=searchresults&type=Repositories

Comment: They don't have an api to share them, but when I am logged in, I can see the forum with all the answers.

Comment: Let the scraping begin!

Answer (score 3):

*Note: I've been thinking about this question since it was asked because I think doing text analysis on human-typed computer programming langauges is a very novel idea. I don't think this answer is spot-on, but I hope that it starts the discussion and gets us to a better answer.*

**The idea**

- [GitHub](https://github.com/) is the source of many programming codes these days, in addition to other resources ([data sets](http://blog.okfn.org/2013/07/02/git-and-github-for-data/), [code snippets](https://gist.github.com/), [writing](https://github.com/showcases/writing), [team projects](https://github.com/showcases/projects-that-power-github), [etc](https://github.com/showcases)).
- Many courses and contests require or suggest posting code to GitHub. For that reason, you have many implementations of the same "homework" or assignment.

**Option 1:**

- [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/) is a *predictive modeling and analytics* competition (contest) platform with many projects and 95,000 participants ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaggle)).
- Participants may post their code submissions to GitHub.

*Steps:*

- Visit GitHub and search "kaggle" - [direct link](https://github.com/search?q=kaggle&ref=cmdform)
- The left menu bar has a breakdown by programming language. Kaggle is heavy with R and Python. The popularity of Java with data-science people is decreasing (more info here). Or maybe it is just Java in general - [N-grams link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Java%20code/code,Java%20programming%20language/programming%20language,%20Java%20developer/developer&year_start=1990&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1;,%28Java%20code%20/%20code%29;,c0;.t1;,%28Java%20programming%20language%20/%20programming%20language%29;,c0;.t1;,%28Java%20developer%20/%20developer%29;,c0), [indeed.com job trends](http://www.indeed.com/jobtrends?q=sql,%20java,%20python,%20nosql&l=).

[image: Search results from "kaggle"]

- So let's choose Python from the filter - [search results](https://github.com/search?l=Python&q=kaggle&ref=cmdform&type=Repositories).
- One recent contest was a handwritten digit recognizer. 36 Python results for searching "[kaggle digit](https://github.com/search?q=kaggle%20digit&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults)" and 30 "[kaggle digits](https://github.com/search?q=kaggle%20digits&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults)" on GitHub. Here is a [random example](https://github.com/canerturkmen/digits/blob/master/kaggle.py) of code.
- You can see [contests have the largest turnout](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions), and then create GitHub searches for those in particular. After some digging you may find one that is Java-centric.
- These repositories can be easily and openly be obtained. If you aren't familiar with Git, you can download all the code, or use their [API](http://developer.github.com/) to search and collect code that meets your criterea. Here is the documentation about [API search](http://developer.github.com/v3/search/).

**Option 2:**

- Similar to above, but for [MOOCs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massive_open_online_course) from places like Coursera instead of Kaggle.
- These online courses often encourage or require posting code to GitHub.
- One example: 173 Java results with tons of Java code for a course called "[Programming Mobile Applications for Android Handheld Systems](https://www.coursera.org/course/android)" - [GitHub search results](https://github.com/search?l=Java&nwo=aporter%2Fcoursera-android&q=coursera+android&ref=cmdform&search_target=global&type=Repositories).
- With deeper searching you can find tons of code for identical project descriptions.

**Option 3:**

- Other contests: e.g. [here](https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=contest&ref=searchresults&s=&type=Repositories) or [here](http://google-opensource.blogspot.ch/2013/12/google-code-in-programming-competition.html)
- [For example...](https://github.com/kijiji-ca/2013-coding-contest)

Answer (score 2):

[Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code) might help you in your task :

> Rosetta Code is a programming chrestomathy site. The idea is to
>   present solutions to the same task in as many different languages as
>   possible, to demonstrate how languages are similar and different, and
>   to aid a person with a grounding in one approach to a problem in
>   learning another. Rosetta Code currently has 711 tasks, 131 draft
>   tasks, and is aware of 530 languages, though we do not (and cannot)
>   have solutions to every task in every language.

You can find all the programming tasks on the [relevant page](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category%3aProgramming_Tasks) and on the [page with candidates](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category%3aDraft_Programming_Tasks).

Comment: Thanks but for a given problem each solution is written in a different different language. +1 though as it might be useful someday!

Comment: Oops, I didn't read your question properly indeed.