# Data sets for small human written programs

Tags: data-request, software

Where can I find a data set with large set of relatively small (<500 LOC) computer programs. Programs should be consistent in language used. can be written in any one language (Javascript preferable).

I do not want large project code bases. Aim is to find small independent programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [Github.com](http://github.com)? There are millions of lines of code from different programs of varying lengths. Github also [has an API](https://developer.github.com/v3/).

Comment: I tried that some time back. But according to API what I can get is large set of .js files from project repositories. But it gets hard to sort out dependencies and to extract independent files out of it. Any ideas ?

Comment: Code contests would be an option, but for javascript there may be not so many options compared to python. See here for more details https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/1868/1511

Comment: @Zack, probably [Github Gists](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/) are slightly more suitable.